# How to retrieve name of element in list (data frame) to use it as a title of the plot?

Tags: r, list, lattice

So briefly and without further ado - is it possible to retrieve only a name of element in list and use it as a main title of plot?

Let me explain - example:

Let's create a random df:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- runif(4)
c <- runif(4)
d <- runif(4)
e <- runif(4)
f <- runif(4)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
head(df)
  a         b         c         d          e          f
1 1 0.9694204 0.9869154 0.5386678 0.39331278 0.15054698
2 2 0.8949330 0.9910894 0.1009689 0.03632476 0.15523628
3 3 0.4930752 0.7179144 0.6957262 0.36579883 0.32006026
4 4 0.4850141 0.5539939 0.3196953 0.14348259 0.05292068
```

Then I want to create a list of data frame (based on this above) with specific columns to make a plot. In other words I'd like to make plot where first column of df (a) will be x axis on the plot and columns b,c,d,e and gonna represent values on y axis on the plot. Yes there'll be 5 plots - that's the point!

So my idea was to write some simple function which be able to create a list of df's based on that created above so:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  a <- df[1]
  b <- x
  aname <- "x_label"
  bname <- "y_label"
  df <- data.frame(a,b)
  names(df) <- c(aname,bname)
  return(df)
}
```

Run it for all (specified) columns:

```
df_s <- apply(df[,2:6], 2, function(x) my_fun(x))
```

So I have now:

```
class(df_s)
[1] "list"
str(df_s)
List of 5
 $ b:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x_label: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ y_label: num [1:4] 0.969 0.895 0.493 0.485
 $ c:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x_label: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ y_label: num [1:4] 0.987 0.991 0.718 0.554
 $ d:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x_label: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ y_label: num [1:4] 0.539 0.101 0.696 0.32
 $ e:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x_label: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ y_label: num [1:4] 0.3933 0.0363 0.3658 0.1435
 $ f:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x_label: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ y_label: num [1:4] 0.1505 0.1552 0.3201 0.0529
```

Something that I wanted, **but here's the question**. **I'd like to create a plot for every df in my list... As a result I want 5 plots with main titles  b, c, d, e, f respectively** Axis labels are the same name of the plot isn't... So I tried:

```
lapply(df_s, function(x) plot(x[2] ~ x[1], data = x, main = ???))
```

What should be instead of question marks? I tried `main = names(df_s)[x]` however it didin't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following works. However, I think it might be best to use `ggplot2` instead of the `plot` function (unless you are saving the plots inside inside `lapply`).

```
lapply(1 : length(df_s), function(x) 
    plot(df_s[[x]][,2] ~ df_s[[x]][,1], 
         xlab = names(df_s[[x]])[1],
         ylab = names(df_s[[x]])[1],
         main = names(df_s[x])))
```

## With ggplot2

```
plot_lst <- lapply(seq_along(df_s), function(i) {
            ggplot(df_s[[i]], aes(x=x_label, y=y_label)) + 
            geom_point() + 
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
            ggtitle(names(df_s)[i]) })
```

Comment: Actually I'd like to create those 5 plots and save them in one pdf. So firstly `pdf('plots.pdf')` then `lapply(...)` and `dev.off()`. I decided to use `dotplot()` from `lattice` package, however I'll check `ggplot2`

Comment: I have included the `ggplot2` option just in case.

Comment: Yes, I got it with `ggplot2`, on my data set, very thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. I think the solution with the `plot` works too.